# blazeds converts BigDecimal to string

Tags: oracle, blazeds, bigdecimal

I have a Flex application that uses blazeds to connect to a Java backend. Using remoting, I give a call to an API to run a SELECT statement on a table (using conventional JDBC classes) in a Oracle database.

The table has 2 columns:

```
PRODUCT_CODE of type NVARCHAR2(32) and
DEMAND of type NUMBER(10, 0)
```

My Java API is as follows:

```
public List<?> getQueryResult(String query) {
  Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connStr, userName, password);
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

  ArrayList<?> result = new ArrayList<?>();
  while(rs.next()) {
    Object[] itemArray = new Object[2];
    itemArray[0] = rs.getObject(1);
    itemArray[1] = rs.getObject(2);
    result.add(itemArray);
  }

  return result;
}
```

In my Flex side, I have a handler for result event of this remote operation:

```
private function onResult(e:ResultEvent) : void {
  var result:ArrayCollection = (e.result as ArrayCollection);
}
```

Strangely, the values corresponding to DEMAND column are automatically converted to string (I debugged to find out that in backend, these were BigDecimal)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes indeed, the BigDecimal from Java is converted to String in ActionScript, as you can read in the [developer guide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=serialize_data_2.html). There is no BigDecimal in ActionScript so it was the only option - you cannot convert any BigDecimal to int or float.

If you are sure that your value represented as NUMBER(10,0) has values in the interval -2,147,483,648 - 2,147,483,647 you can convert it to an int in java - see the code below:

```
itemArray[1] = ((BigDecimal)rs.getObject(2)).intValue();
```